# Add attribute to a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript variable (ex: myElement), that holds a div with class name myClass like shown below.

```
<div>
    <div class="myClass">
        <h1>My Div</h1>
        <div id="1">Div one Content</div>
        <h2>Headline two</h2>
        <div id="2">Div two Content </div>
    </div>
    <div class="myClass">
        <h1>My Div</h1>
        <div id="1">Div one Content</div>
        <h2>Headline two</h2>
        <div id="2">Div two Content </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add an attribute (ex: data-index) to the div having class 'myClass' through jascsript or jQuery so that it could look like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="myClass" data-index="index1">
        <h1>My Div</h1>
        <div id="1">Div one Content</div>
        <h2>Headline two</h2>
        <div id="2">Div two Content </div>
    </div>

    <div class="myClass" data-index="index2">
        <h1>My Div</h1>
        <div id="1">Div one Content</div>
        <h2>Headline two</h2>
        <div id="2">Div two Content </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can you achieve this?

**Please note: I have this div in a javascript variable called myElement** and the following code

```
myElement.attr('data-index','index')
```

does not work.

**Update:**

I could try like First appending the div stored in variable myElement to the DOM, then add the attribute:

```
$('div.myClass').attr('data-index','index');
```

but the problem is in the DOM I have like 100s of div with the class myClass.

Comment: How are you defining `myElement`? Is it a jQuery object?

Comment: In order for this to be answerable, it needs to have more jQuery (show more code plz).

Comment: Your code works as far as you've shown it: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2oLt7hss/1/

Comment: This looks exactly like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).  Putting an attribute on an element solves some problem, but the problem you haven't described only your solution to your problem.

Comment: Has this problem been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var newAttr = document.createAttribute("data-index");
newAttr.value = "[What you want the index to be]";

// Will set data-index for first .myClass in newElement
newElement.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0].setAttributeNode(newAttr);

// Will set data-index for every .myClass in newElement
newElement.getElementsByClassName("myClass").map(function(node) {
    node.setAttributeNode(newAttr)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well, the better way is you create the attributes while you are creating HTML.

But you can do what you want using jquery iterate function (Jquery.each): http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

```
var myElements = $('div.myClass'),
    i = 0;

$.each( myElements , function( i ) {
    $(this).attr('data-index','index'+(i+1));
});
```